# TimeDistributed vs. TimeDistributedDense Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I have gone through the [official documentation](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) but still can't understand what actually `TimeDistributed` does as a layer in Keras model?

I couldn't understand the difference between `TimeDistributed` and `TimeDistributedDense`? When will someone use `TimeDistributedDense`? Is it only to reduce training data set? Does it have other benefit?

Can anyone explain with a precise example that what these two type of layer wrappers does?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So - basically the `TimeDistributedDense` was introduced first in early versions of Keras in order to apply a `Dense` layer stepwise to sequences. `TimeDistributed` is a Keras wrapper which makes possible to get any static (non-sequential) layer and apply it in a sequential manner. So if e.g. your layer accepts as an input something of shape `(d1, .., dn)` thanks to `TimeDistributed` wrapper your layer could accept an input with a shape of `(sequence_len, d1, ..., dn)` by applying a layer provided to `X[0,:,:,..,:]`, `X[1,:,...,:]`, `...`, `X[len_of_sequence,:,...,:]`.

An example of such usage might be using a e.g. pretrained convolutional layer to a short video clip by applying `TimeDistributed(conv_layer)` where `conv_layer` is applied to each frame of a clip. It produces the sequence of outputs which might be then consumed by next recurrent or `TimeDistributed` layer.

It's good to know that usage of `TimeDistributedDense` is depreciated and it's better to use `TimeDistributed(Dense)`.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeDistributedDense` is the same than `TimeDistributed` with the only difference that `TimeDistributed` can be used with different types of layer and not just Dense layer.

Keras documentation says that about `TimeDistributed` :

"Note this is strictly equivalent to using `layers.core.TimeDistributedDense`. However what is different about  `TimeDistributed` is that it can be used with arbitrary layers, not just Dense, for instance with a `Convolution2D` layer"